# Router doens't work on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, router

My router was configured to work with windows. I formatted the hard disk and installed ubuntu 12.04. My internet connection works with direct connection from modem, however when I connected the modem and router with an ethernet cable and the router and my laptop with another ethernet cable my internet doesn't work. Chrome is stuck at resolving host. 
On running ifconfig, wlan0 and eth0 does have an ip address in the range I specified in the dhcp server on the router.

D-Link router, DIR-600M, N150.

Dynamic connection.

Router ip : 192.168.2.1

DHCP scope : 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.254

DNS : google dns and the ones provided by isp

neither wireless nor wired connection works through the router.

Comment: To which port on the router is the modem connected?

Comment: Does network manager say you are connected when you click on the network-manager icon? If so, what does it say? It sounds like a dns problem. Try setting your dns to 8.8.8.8 to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes it does say connected. I have tried various combinations of dns addresses google's and the ones provided by isp. @mchid

Comment: It is on the wan port, don't worry about that. @user300458

Comment: Go to Network Menu -> Connection Information -> IPv4 section, what's there?

Comment: It has the settings saved from the direct connection to the modem.

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is to find out if it is a DNS problem or not. First you should try pinging your router (usually on 192.168.0.1), then try pinging googlde DNS (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4).

Comment: Do you have other devices connected to this router? (e.g. smartphone, tablet)

Comment: Not right now but I intend to. @user300458

Comment: Could you explain what does exactly the modem do? as in when you connect it directly to the PC? does it dial through PPPoE or anything similar? Also, since the Windows format and Ubuntu installation, did you do any changes to the router or the modem?

Comment: No the connection is dynamic, any url is type in chrome, redirects me to the login page(a proper webpage), i enter details and that gives me access. When I connect to the router even this page cannot be opened. No  I did not do any changes initially since the windows removal and ubuntu installation. But I did change a few things when the router wasn't working. Although I tried setting up using PPPoE as well in the router settings. That too didn't work. @AzkerM

Answer (score 1):

You should check your current network settings in Ubuntu. While the laptop is connected to router, the IPv4 connection method must be set to "Automatic (DHCP)".